# What signal number do pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal use internally?

Tags: linux, pthreads, signals

Do `pthread_cond_wait` and `pthread_cond_signal` use `sigwait` and `kill` (from `signal.h`), respectively, internally?

If yes, what signal number do they use, I mean, what value is passed to `int kill(pid_t pid, int sig)` as `sig`?

Comment: What does [strace(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) say they use?

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot `strace`. However, I'm not on Linux right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general implementation these don't need regular UNIX signals. Instead, it relies on [atomic operations](http://wiki.osdev.org/Atomic_operation) on a shared memory location and a couple of OS primitives like "sleep" and "wakeup".

Comment: Ok, that's right, but, do you know what "sleep"-and-"wakeup"-like OS primitives are used on Linux?